# Chrome scaling issue

Tags: google-chrome, zooming, scaling

Ever since chrome updated to v.54 it seems to read DPI scale value from the computer to scale the content on the page.

Is there anyway to set the scale to the default 100% on websites using css?

Comment: I found this but nothing seems to work : http://blog.the-ebook-reader.com/2016/10/21/how-to-fix-google-chromes-large-zoomed-in-ui-after-update/

Comment: That is to force the browser to not scale but has to be done from the users end. When developing websites, the scaling might miss-align some elements to the user.

And as i understand some Windows 10 region ship with the default scale set to 125%, which is a whole problem on its own.